# cannot find module cloudinary-core

Tags: cloudinary, stenciljs

git clone https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-starter.git cl-gallery

followed the instruction on
https://cloudinary.com/blog/cloudinary_image_gallery_with_stencil_custom_components

and getting an error message :

cannot find module cloudinary-core  and ../../db

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That blog post doesn't mention that you need to install the `cloudinary-core` package:

```sh
npm install cloudinary-core
```

The error with the `db` module is because of a wrong path. Use `../db` instead.

Comment: changed the path and that helped, but npm install cloudinary-core is required otherwise it would give me another error for the import of cloudinary.